# compress parquet to gzip using properties write.parquet.compression-codec "gzip"

Tags: apache-spark, apache-iceberg

Can you give me an example of compress parquet to gzip? My wish is when I query it to output gzip file. I am working with iceberg table and I am using pyspark language,recommend using property    `write.parquet.compression-codec`

My code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("CSVICEBERG") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.4_2.12:1.3.0") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type", "hive") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.local", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.local.type", "hadoop") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.local.warehouse", "D:\\iceberg_warehouse") \
    .config("spark.sql.defaultCatalog", "local") \
    .config("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "gzip") \
    .config("write.parquet.compression-codec", "gzip") \
    .getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("write.parquet.compression-codec", "gzip")
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE local.test.cnd10 (name STRING,id INT) using iceberg")
spark.sql("INSERT INTO local.test.cnd10 values ('ABC',1)")
```

I tried querying, but the data folder in the local warehouse only receives back parquet files. I hope that when querying, I receive gzip files.